# Magnitude of numbers

Tags: c

Problem : Determine number of pos, neg and zeros entered by the user.

Code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int pos, neg, zero = 0 ;
    char x[7] ; 
    int num = 0 ;
    printf("\nPress Q to quit anytime");
    while( printf("\n") , gets(x)) {
        num = atoi(x) ;
        if( !strcmp(x , "Q")) break ;
        if( num > 0) pos++ ;
        else if (num < 0) neg++ ;
        else zero++ ;
    }
    printf("\nPos nos: %d \tNeg nos: %d \tZeros: %d", pos, neg, zero);
}
```

Here, although neg and zeros are being counted appropriately, positives are not. It always shows positive numbers with an offset of 4196240 ie if there are 4 positive numbers, it will show 4196244.

Whats so special about 4196240? And why is it showing this?

Comment: you are giving an unexpected argument to printf: `gets(x)` which is probably messing with the stack and causing the uninitialized values to behavior this way

Comment: Move the break-condition above the `atoi` line. Also note, you should not use `while` like you do - that is an abuse of the idea. Better make that infinite `while ( 1 )` and break if `fgets` returns `EOF`.

Comment: `char x[7]` is not long enough to hold a numeric string in the range of `int`. As `gets()` has no buffer overrun protection, at least declare an array large enough to hold the range of `int`, or use `fgets()` - preferably both.

Comment: Ok. I'll modify my prog. Thanks for the advise .

Comment: could also just do `int x; while(scanf("%d", &x) != 1) { ... }` and exit on any non-numeric input.

Comment: @RyanHaining . But wouldnt checking of a non numeric input require x to be type char (array) ?

Comment: No, `scanf` returns the number of matches it was able to make with the pattern you gave it.  If it returns `0` here it means that no matches were made (it couldn't scan a number from stdin).  If it gives `1` it means one match was made (successfully read a number).  Once the user enters anything not a number, scanf will return `0`, the condition will become false, and the loop will terminate.

Comment: You can't check to see if it's `"Q"` specifically, but your program doesn't deal with non-numeric inputs anyway.  If I enter "hello" it is counted as a `0`, which is wrong.

Comment: also, use `int main()` **never** `void main()`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. Till now i used strcmp inside while to check. I'll reserve scanf for simple ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize all of the counting variables.  Your declaration only initializes `zero`, leaving `pos` and `neg` uninitialized.

```
int pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0 ;
```

> Whats so special about 4196240 ? And why is it showing this ?

It just happens to be that value when not initialized by you, there's nothing special about it, it's a garbage value.

Comment: To be more specific, uninitialized values are given "garbage" values which are just random numbers in memory which is what Ryan is referring to.

Comment: Even more specific, uninitialized local non-static variables have an *indeterminate* value, and using them (besides initializing them) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thats a bummer. Pardon this noob programmer. Thanks :)

Comment: @lmcphers uninitialized values are **not** given "garbage" values. They are not given any value at all, they have the value that happened to be in their memory space.

Comment: I think "garbage" is a fair colloquial term for them, but "random" isn't.

Comment: I stand corrected!  Though I'm not sure I agree exactly with you @WeatherVane.  They now point to a space in memory and are "given" the value that is at that memory address.  Sure, it's not manually done by the programmer, but they are given some value. Whether they are "given" or "have" that value, they still have that value, I'm not sure I understand your discrepancy. I think maybe you are confused at my wording which I admit was poor.